# PHP similar_text pick the highest value

Tags: php

I use the similar_text in while loop like that :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$similiar_name = $row["f_name"];
similar_text($prototype_name, $similiar_name, $percent);
}
```

How can i echo the highest $percent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the calculated results in an array, then sort that array and extract the top result

```
$similarities = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $similiar_name = $row["f_name"];
    similar_text($prototype_name, $similiar_name, $percent);
    $similarities[$similiar_name] = $percent;
}

rsort($similarities);
echo $similarities[0];
```