# PHP similar_text how to echo colosest similar text

Tags: php

I use the similar_text in while loop like that :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$similiar_name = $row["f_name"];
similar_text($prototype_name, $similiar_name, $percent);
}
```

How can i echo the $similiar_name with the highest $percent?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074390/php-similar-text-pick-the-highest-value/30074466#30074466 - is this homework or something?

Comment: LOLOL is from online course !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the calculated results in an array, then sort that array and extract the top result

```
$similarities = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $similiar_name = $row["f_name"];
    similar_text($prototype_name, $similiar_name, $percent);
    $similarities[$similiar_name] = $percent;
}

arsort($similarities);
echo array_keys($similarities)[0];
```

or if you don't have an up-to-date version of PHP that supports array dereferencing, replace

```
echo array_keys($similarities)[0];
```

with

```
$words = array_keys($similarities)
echo $words[0];
```

Comment: i did this echo array_keys($similarities)[0];  and the result is : 0

Comment: @James Your php version is?

Comment: @Rizier123 its 5.6. i also tryed $words = array_keys($similarities)
echo $words[0]; but same results . "0"

Comment: Do some basic debugging: var_dump() $similarities, and see what's there

Comment: @Mark Baker array(12) { [0]=> float(90.909090909091) [1]=> float(45.454545454545) [2]=> float(16.216216216216) [3]=> float(14.814814814815) [4]=>  float(12.5) [5]=> float(12.121212121212) [6]=> float(11.428571428571) [7]=> float(10.810810810811) [8]=> float(7.5471698113208) [9]=> float(7.4074074074074) [10]=> float(4.3478260869565) [11]=> float(2.8571428571429) }

Comment: I want to get the $similiar_name not the  $percent. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: My bad: replace `rsort($similarities);` with `arsort($similarities);`..... I've already edited it into the answer